# how to call complete my custom php page without header and footer of wordpress with shortcode or a custom page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type, shortcode

I am creating a Plugin, as that plugin activated a "custom post type" also created named "documentation" also a page named "Documentation" created.

Now I want that whenever "Documentation" page is viewed it should show completely my custom php page. I dont want wordpress header, footer etc.

I want this page completely in my hand.I tried with shortcode, I created shortcode and put it in page content but when this page is viewed it shows shortcode content with worpress theme layout (header, footer).

Following is my code.

```
function documentation_fun( $atts ) {
        ob_start();
        include 'documentation.php';
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    add_shortcode( '3pane-documentation', 'documentation_fun' );
```

I am creating this in my plugin.Please suggest me the best way to achieve my goal.

---

**EDIT**

I found something else as well, there is a filter for the content

```
function magicalendar_get_event_page( $content ) {
        global $post;
         if ($post->post_title == ' Documentation') {
              $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/documentation.php';
         }
         return $single_template;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'magicalendar_get_event_page' );
```

but this is just returning file path not the content of file (html). Also header and footer still coming which I dont want.

---

I found hook by myself :) it is add_filter('taxonomy_template');

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove header and footer then create your custom page template. its best option.

Create your template file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: My Custom Page Template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
```

And in end select this template in page.

so it will not print header and footer.

It will only print header and footer when you call.

```
get_header();

get_sidebar();

get_footer();
```

if not then it will out put your content only with custom header and footer.

Comment: yeh in your plugin also you can call your custom page. you can make archive page and set it on it.

Comment: is it your custom post type? and its archive page ?